# Show element as soon as form is valid

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to show element as soon as my form becomes valid. According to flutter docs I need to use _formKey.currentState.validate() but in the docs it is used on button click, while I'm trying to use it to show/hide element.

**Working code (as used in flutter tutorial)**

```
return Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      TextFormField(
        autovalidate: true,
        validator: validateName,
      ),

      RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () => _formKey.currentState.validate()
              ? print('valid')
              : print('not valid'))
```

**My code with (INVALID MEMER OF NULL: 'validate) error**

```
return Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: Column(
    children: [
      TextFormField(
        autovalidate: true,
        validator: validateName,
       ),

      _formKey.currentState.validate()
          ? Container(child: Text('valid'))
          : Container(child: Text('not valid'))
```

Comment: So you want to show/hide an element when button is clicked and then if valid, then element will show up, else, hide the element, right?

Comment: No, I'm trying to show element as soon as textfield is valid and hide as soon as its not. First snippet of code I presented is just there as working example of  usage of _formKey.currentState.validate().

Comment: so that means there is a case related to the textfield, right? Can I take a case of textfield when the word length becomes 4, then the element will show up, else will not?

Comment: I have my validator working. The problem is that when I call _formKey.currentState.validate() it is null at first, so I get the error.

Comment: Can you show me the code for `validateName` please?

Comment: `String validateName(String value) {
  if (value.length < 3)
    return 'Name must be more than 2 charater';
  else
    return null;
}`

Comment: I guess the problem is with `null` return which is being checked while the data length is less than 3. Do you want a similar functionality, **but without the usage of `validate`, it will do the same job, which you want**? If, yes then I have the code ready for you. You might just need to make some small changes and you are good to go

Comment: Or do one thing, `return ""` and empty string, not `null` and check. Let me know

Comment: I tried to return not null and it's still same error

Comment: You want my other option to try. It is not using validate

Comment: I need to somehow check for validation after the form is not empty, I'm not sure how to do it yet

Comment: Post it in answers and I'll try it

Comment: I think I figured it out. I needed to use onChanged property in my textformfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer for you will be to use `TextFormField` [onChanged](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/ValueChanged.html), which is  of type `ValueChanged`, which keeps track of the changes you make in your `TextFormField`

**Advantage**

> You will be able to keep a track of the text changes, and show/hide content based upon that

**Disadvantage**

> Each `TextField` should be maintaining the `bool` for the different `TextField` to keep a track of the items

It is like a workaround, so can use in this way. **I am using a single TextFormField to show how it works**, you can then work on ther `TextFormField` and get it up and running.

**FINAL SOLUTION**

```
       bool isValid = false;
       final TextEditingController _controller = new TextEditingController();

       Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
             TextFormField(
               decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter your data'),
               controller: _controller,
               onChanged: (String val){
                 setState((){
                   if(val.length >= 4) isValid = true;
                   else isValid = false;
                 });
               }
             ),
             SizedBox(height: 20.0),
             isValid ? Text('Valid String', textAlign: TextAlign.center) : Text('Name must be more than 3 character', textAlign: TextAlign.center)
          ]
        )
```

**SOLUTION:** For various, you must check whether all the different bools are true or not, based upon that, you can show/hide the data.

**RESULT**

[image: RESULTANT GIF]

Let me know if is of any use to you :)

Comment: Thanks @user1743703. Happy to help :)